# Is there a way to easily disable output to my second monitor to improve my video performance in a game?

Tags: windows-7, performance

I have a Radeon HD 5250 that has dual output.  In a particular game that I'm playing, it's choppy even at the absolute lowest graphics settings and resolution.  During that time, my second display is completely active as though I wasn't playing a full screen game on the primary monitor.

Would disabling the secondary output improve video performance on the primary output?

If so, then is there an application for Windows 7 that will easily and temporarily disable the second monitor?  I know I could go into the control panel to disable it, but then it shrinks the size of my desktop, potentially moving icons around, and it will shift all my open windows to the primary monitor, etc.  It seems like a problem somebody else would have solved already.

Comment: Is the CPU connected to 2 monitors simultaneously?

Comment: @AbhishekSha: Yep, one PC with a single, dual-output video card attached to two different monitors.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to disable second monitor while keeping virtual desktop intact. Virtual desktop (the big desktop you have that spans multiple monitors) is tightly integrated with video driver and monitors. Your best bet is not to place any shortcuts on second desktop, so disabling second monitor will only reduce desktop size and don't mess your icons.

Also, disabling additional minitors have very little impact on game performance since the limiting factor for game is 3D graphics and it is not affecting additional desktops if not configured. Your problem may be in the video card used, since Radeon HD 5250 is a low-end video card by itself.

You can check your video card performance at this site: http://www.notebookcheck.net/